# C#: Writing a RTF (Text) file to system drive

Tags: c#

I have a program which contains a richTextBox and a Button. Upon clicking the button, the program gets the text from richTextBox and saves it to a predefined location stored in a string variable.
If I change this location to C drive which is my System Drive, it won't allow me to do it and throws a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`.

I am also the admininstrator of my PC. Is there any way that I can get permissions or work something out to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

I use the following code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string temp = location;
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(temp);
    file.WriteLine(this.richTextBox1.Rtf);
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: I have a made an application to manage my classes' notes and upload to the skydrive folder : string temp = "C:\\Users\\MuhammadWaqas\\SkyDrive";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to write files directly to the root of the `c:` drive often cause problems, such as the exception you're seeing.

Try storing your file somewhere else. A good way of getting a safe folder is to use the `SpecialFolder` enumeration: *(change it to Desktop, MyDocuments, or whatever might be appropriate in your case)*

```
string temp
  = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "myFile.txt")

System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(temp);
```

---

Considering your update, try this instead:

```
string temp
  = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\MuhammadWaqas\SkyDrive", "myFile.txt");
```

As pcnThird suggested, you could save it to `"myFile.rtf"` instead and take advantage of the file type, assuming you're going to be opening the file and reading the contents outside of your app.

Comment: Thanks Grant! Actually, I'm trying to store the file to SkyDrive folder so that it is automatically synched but I am not able to manage to copy the file to the sky drive folder.

Comment: Since the text is coming from a RichTextBox, you might want to save it as an `.rtf`file to keep its formatting :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a file name instead of a folder, try changing location to "C:\Users\MuhammadWaqas\SkyDrive\test.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Check your location. You might be trying to write to a non existent or restricted location